# Calling Parent methods and accessing private variable in a Parent class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm trying to get the following code to work, but I can't find good-enough documentation on how C++ handles public vs. private inheritance to allow me to do what I want.  If someone could explain why I can't access `Parent::setSize(int)` or `Parent::size` using private inheritance or `Parent::size` using public inheritance.  To solve this, to I need a `getSize()` and `setSize()` method in Parent?

```
class Parent {
    private:
        int size;

    public:
        void setSize(int s);
};

void Parent::setSize(int s) {
    size = s;
}

class Child : private Parent {
    private:
        int c;

    public:
        void print();
};

void Child::print() {
    cout << size << endl;
}

int main() {
    Child child;

    child.setSize(4);

    child.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use private inheritance, all public and protected members of the base class become private in the derived class. In your example, `setSize` becomes private in `Child`, so you can't call it from `main`.

Also, `size` is already private in `Parent`. Once declared private, a member always remains private to the base class regardless of the type of inheritance.

Comment: yep, and private members are not inherited, that's why you can't access private members of the base class

Comment: @Ned Batchelder: That's why I voted for your answer. :) I'm not sure what exactly the OP wants, because otherwise normal public inheritance would have worked fine.

Answer (score 26):

Change Parent to:

```
protected: int size;
```

If you want to access the `size` member from a derived class,  but not from outside the class, then you want `protected`.

Change Child to:

```
class Child: public Parent
```

When you say `class Child: private Parent`, you are saying it should be a secret that Child is a Parent.  Your `main` code makes it clear that you want Child to be manipulated as a Parent, so it should be public inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access private data-members of other classes. If you want to access private attributes of a superclas, you should do so via public or a protected accessors. As for the rest, see @casablanca's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009505/calling-parent-methods-and-accessing-private-variable-in-a-parent-class/4009520#4009520).

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Parent {
private:
    int size;

public:
    void setSize(int s);

    int fun()  //member function from base class to access the protected variable 
    {
        return size;
    }
};

void Parent::setSize(int s) {
size = s;
}

class Child : private Parent {
private:
    int c;

public:
    void print();


    using Parent::setSize; //new code line
    using Parent::fun;     //new code line
};

void Child::print() {
    cout << fun() << endl;
}

int main() {
    Child child;

    child.setSize(4);

    child.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend you [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).  When giving an answer it is preferable to give some explanation as to WHY your answer is the one.